# How to convert Gridview row to int OR How to promote the row down and above

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspxgridview

I'm trying to make a list.
When I select a row in Gridview, red line with the lines above and below

**THIS THE SIDE OF THE ASP**

```
 protected void rowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{

    switch (e.CommandName)
    {

        case "PIC":

                ImageButton i = (ImageButton)e.CommandSource;
                GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)i.NamingContainer;
                row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                **//problem**
                row = Convert.ToInt32(row + 1);
                //problem
                Session["Row"] = row;
     }
 }
```

How can i convert the row to number for add one and subtract one
And how i convert the int num back to row type

---

its not working, i can catch the row number  by this code

```
ImageButton i = (ImageButton)e.CommandSource;
                GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)i.NamingContainer;
```

but when i try to do what u offer its non working
all i need is to take the:

```
Session["Row"] = row;
```

and promote\decrease the row by one

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast a GridViewRow to an int, but GridViewRow has a RowIndex property, see the MSDN documentation here: [GridViewRow.RowIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.rowindex.aspx)

Comment: ok so if i caught the row that i clicked on ,Is there a way to turn the next line?

Answer (score 0):

e.CommandArgument is the zero-based integer index of the row that's generating the event.

So e.CommandArgument - 1 would be the row before, and + 1 would be the row after.  Make sure to check for the boundaries of your rowset (e.g. no negative indexes, no index greater than length - 1)

edit:  to get these rows, you'd do something like (no guarantees, IDE isn't open):

```
    GridViewRow gvrBefore = null;

    if ( ((int)e.CommandArgument) > 0) {
       gvrBefore = MyGridObject.Rows[((int)e.CommandArgument) - 1];
    }
```

Comment: its not working, i can catch the row number  by this code

ImageButton i = (ImageButton)e.CommandSource;
                GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)i.NamingContainer;

but when i try to do what u offer its non working
all i need is to take the:
 Session["Row"] = row;
and promote\decrease the row by one